# Django 1.11 - static file not found

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm working on a Django project (Django 1.11), and I'm trying to use static file. 
This is my project structure:

```
|project_name
|---- app_name
|-------- src
|------------ static
|---------------- css
|-------------------- bootstrap
|------------------------ bootstrap.min.css
|-------- templates
|------------ base.html
|------------ first_template.html
|-------- views
|------------ first_view.py
|---- project_name
|-------- settings.py
```

In settings.py file, I have *django.contrib.staticfiles* in INSTALLED_APPS and I set *STATIC_URL* variable as follow:

```
STATIC_URL = '/src/static/'
```

Then, I'd like use static files in base template, and this is what I've done:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I load *first_template.html*, and so also the *base.html* file, the bootstrap.min.css file is not found (404).

I know that is a trivial question, but i really don't understand what i'm missing. I have checked a lot of similar SO questions without success, also because most of them refer to old django versions  
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using customised path, why dont you tell the django where to find it.. use this in settings and it shall work fine.

#### option 1:

in case you are serious about preserving your file structure

```
#settings.py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ...
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/src/static') # build appropriate path
)
```

**UPDATE:**

#### option 2:

move the static folder to where `manage.py` exists or into the child of app.

example:

```
...manage.py
...static
...app/
```

or

```
...manage.py
...app/static
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your first option works well, but also the STATIC_URL="/static/" should be modified.

Answer (score 1):

`STATIC_URL` only control the prefix of static files URL (i.e web address). It doesn't control their physical location on disk.

Move your static files from `app_name/src/static/` to `app_name/static/` and that should fix it

Edit:
If you want to keep directory structure as it is, you have couple of options

1. Manually add your static file directories to `STATICFILES_DIRS`
2. Create a class that inherit from `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` and set the source_dir attribute

`from django.contrib.staticfiles.finders import AppDirectoriesFinder
class MyAppDirFinder(AppDirectoriesFinder):
         source_dir = "src/static"`

Then you can add your class to `STATICFILES_FINDERS`

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
'myapp.finders.MyAppDirFinder',

]
```

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#static-files

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i prefer keep the project structure as is

Answer (score 0):

Indside static folder you need to create a folder with app name

Now your folder structure is

```
   |-------- src
    |------------ static
    |---------------- css
    |-------------------- bootstrap
    |------------------------ bootstrap.min.css
```

Change it to

```
|-------- src
|------------ static
|-------------------app_name
|--------------------------- css
|-------------------- ----------bootstrap
|---------------------------------------- bootstrap.min.css
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend'),)
```

or

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=()
```

in your settings.
Then it should work.
Took me a long time to find this.